# How to change SMS type with AWS.SNS.publish

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am using AWS-SDK for Node.js and I would like to change the SMS type when using the SNS `publish` method, i.e. from `Promotional` to `Transactional`. 
I know I have to use the `MessageAttributes` property but the documentation is not quite clear how I should do this.

What parameter or property should I add to `MessageAttributes` object/map?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a long search this is what worked for me:

```
AWS = require('aws-sdk')

(new AWS.SNS()).publish({
   Message: 'Message',
   PhoneNumber: '+XXX',
   MessageAttributes: {
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
       DataType: 'String',
       StringValue: 'Transactional'
    }
 });
```

The attribute you must add is `'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'`

Comment: Strange as I get the following error when setting this exact key:
`Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon.`

Comment: Holy hell this was hard to find.

Comment: It's ridiculous how unhelpful AWS docs are and so many other answers, especially for something that I believe is so common. For other's viewing this, you may also need to contact AWS support to allow your account to send SMS messages if this does not work. I had to enable additional SNS SMS failure logging to finally see the error that was preventing me from sending OTP messages. See my error here: https://imgur.com/hFGYpsh